# Blending eggs for omelette?

Tags: eggs

When I was preparing eggs at my uncle's house, since he was a techie, he insisted on blending the eggs in a miniature food processor as opposed to, say, beating them. Is there any advantage to this practice besides looking sophisticated?

Answer (score 4):

Using a food-processor to beat scrambled eggs is going to over-beat them. Over-beaten eggs will turn rubbery.

> The American Egg Board describes well-beaten eggs as "frothy and evenly colored." This generally takes about 20 to 35 seconds of beating - do not over beat. You want to get them to a uniform color and texture with minimal amounts egg white showing. A fork works as well as a wire whisk but requires a slight bit more time and more energy. Use a bowl that is deep enough to support vigorous whisking.
>    - [What's Cooking America](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Eggs/ScrambledOmelette.htm)

To make the *perfect* French omelet, America's Test Kitchen *counts* (yes, at that even *I* rolled my eyes) precisely 80 turns of the whisk. The object being to thoroughly mix the eggs while allowing the curds to be creamy when formed. Over-mixing the eggs makes the curds dry and rubbery.

Tell your uncle that sophisticated cooks use a whisk or a fork. Once the eggs are in the pan, you can look *really sophisticated* by stirring with chopsticks.

Comment: Or don't tell your uncle anything and just make a mental not to not pick up his habits. :D